# How can I define a variable's type in the app.MapControllerRoute() pattern in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

Does anyone know how I can do that in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC ? I want to define the variables types of year and month

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MoviesByReleaseDate",
    "movies/released/{year}/{month}",
    new { controller = "Movies", action = "ByRelease Date" },
    new { year = @"\d{4}", month = @"\d{2}" }
);
```

Comment: Why  do you  need it? there are another ways to route.

Comment: You can try to refer to `Regular expressions in constraints` and `Custom route constraints` in the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: @Serge I need it because I am learning ASP.NET Core 6 MVC with a course and I don't know which way I should choose

Comment: @YiyiYou thanks for the documentation link, I think this will help me

Comment: @JordivanCuijlenborg You have to use a default map route .  I never seen that anybody was trying to use what are you trying. It doesn't make much sense

Comment: @JordivanCuijlenborg Just put your fanny route  as an attribute to a controller or better to action.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes more sense. It's much cleaner